# Psychology of cheaters

Tags: personality, personality-disorder

I am curious to know that what kind of psychological factors influence serial cheaters. Infidelity or adultery both are considered immoral in majority of civilized societies around the world. But it doesn't stop here In many societies its generally believed that cheaters don't change their behaviour easily.

> Once a cheater always a cheater.

I also did some research and know that cheaters have narcissistic personality disorders. They think that they are the most beautiful or important people around.

Are there any other factors which may effect the behavior of serial cheaters?

I'm thinking of factors like oppression at home, overly strict parents, childhood trauma, etcetera.

What kind of kicks may change their behavior?